# What is the English word for the Hindi word 'Jugaad' which means attaining a result in a crude/easy way?

Tags: translation, word-formation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a single noun in English for “jerry-rigged”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94806/is-there-a-single-noun-in-english-for-jerry-rigged)

[Jugaad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugaad) in Hindi refers to an object that has been produced/modified in a crude/primitive way. I do not know its English translation.

Is there a word or brief phrase in English that means  attaining a workable (but perhaps crude) result in an easy way?