# What is the word for using something for other than its intended purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I think this is originally a term used in biology or evolution theory. I heard it in a youtube video but I cannot find it now.

**Edit:** This word does not have negative connotations. For instance, an animal may develop a different way to use an organ intended for something else. Or you can use a big book as a door stop.

Comment: This word does not have negative connotations. For instance, an animal may develop a different way to use an organ intended for something else. Or you can use a big book as a door stop.

Comment: Why not [*repurposing*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/repurpose?q=repurposing)?

Comment: I think repurposing works as well; in fact I was looking to repurpose exaptation to mean repurpose.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If I presumed I had clarity of the question, I would answer it with *malapropism* - but I will not since I have scant idea if that is what you would be looking for, since it has nothing to do with biological Evolution.

Comment: As a biologist, I'd be more inclined to refer to an original purpose rather than intended purpose - "intention" (and to a lesser extent, "purpose") sounds like intelligent design.

Comment: Not a general-purpose answer, but just in case it works for your context, see "off-label".  In a casual sense, people use hemorrhoid cream off-label to reduce dark patches under the eyes.  In other news, I haven't tried that, but I still would advise against it.

Comment: You may find value in the answers and discussion here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94806/is-there-a-single-noun-in-english-for-jerry-rigged

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer: [exaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaptation).

Comment: Your title is dubious . Exaptation is a change in function of a trait during evolution ,( the purpose of it changes but there is no mention of

Comment: Other use than intended purpose.

Comment: Though I would like to know the answer of the title question and not the anticipated question.

Comment: in a biological sense, i believe this is most certainly the correct word. for those looking for something WITH the negative connotations, "subvert" comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

Shoehorn perhaps?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shoehorn

> Verb  1.  shoehorn - fit for a specific purpose even when not well
>   suited

Answer (score 2):

Using "improvise" and "improvisation" in a sentence to illustrate the meaning:

> We lacked the purpose-built equipment to do the task, so we had to improvise, using only the tools available.
>
> Our improvisation of using a garden hoe to mix the cement worked well.

Answer (score 1):

@Argot -what's the answer to the title?

***ad hoc***
Latin, meaning: *for this* -[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc)

> ad hoc can also mean makeshift solutions, shifting contexts to create new meanings, inadequate planning, or improvised events.

ad hoc \ˈad-ˈhäk, -ˈhōk; ˈäd-ˈhōk\ adjective -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc)

> 1,b : formed or used for specific or immediate problems or needs 
>   2: fashioned from whatever is immediately available: improvised

Answer (score 0):

Anomaly? maybe the world anomaly could be used to describe this practice or

anomalous-being out of the ordinary that was an anomalous year for the housing industry, so the number of starts is anything but typical
Synonyms aberrant, aberrated, abnormal, exceptional, atypical, especial, exceeding, extraordinaire, extraordinary, freak, odd, peculiar, phenomenal, preternatural, rare, singular, uncommon, uncustomary, unique, unusual, unwonted

Answer (score 0):

Palimpsest. A beautiful word and a magical thing. "Something such as a work of art that has many levels of meaning, types of style, etc. that build on each other," according to the Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: The Shabaka Stone in the British Museum was once a monumental stela recording events 1000's of years ago but became a millstone for grinding grain and then a part of a wall. It carries all those complex histories in one simple stone 'wheel'.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this word *improvise* or *improvisation*

Comment: Not my downvote, could be the voter needs to be convinced. Could you provide a definition from an online dictionary, or make a sentence with your suggestion? (I think you're on the right track btw)

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou A that this might well be the best verb suggestion. It's a shame that the user who put it forward never attempted to develop the suggestion into a complete answer, with (for example) a suitable definition of the suggested term and a brief explanation of how it meets the questioner's conditions.